# how do I rerender the Screen A when I go back to screen A from Screen B?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Behavior expected :

- Screen A onclick navigates to Screen B -> finally navigates to Screen C
- Screen C sets data to async storage -> BackHandler navigates to Screen A
- Screen A checks the change in state rerenders the screen with the change

But
Screen A is not rerendering until I reload or make any change manually

Screen A useffect() code:

```
const [nutrition_assessment_age, setnutritionassessmentage] = useState(null);
useEffect(() => {
    console.log('nutri assess age', nutrition_assessment_age);
    getNutritionAssessmentage();
    getHomeTabMainAPI();
    if (isValidObject(User) && isValidObject(mSChildId)) {
      if (loadApi == true) {
        getHomeTabMainAPI();
        setLoadApi(false);
        setSelectedChild(getChildFromUserChildrenList());
      }
    } else {
      if (!isValidObject(User) || !isValidObject(mSChildId)) {
        getUserData();
      }
    }
  }, [User, mSChildId, loadApi, nutrition_assessment_age]);
```

Screen C Backhandler Code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    retreiveData();
    BackHandler.addEventListener('hardwareBackPress', handleBackButtonOnnclick);
    return () => {
      BackHandler.removeEventListener(
        'hardwareBackPress',
        handleBackButtonOnnclick,
      );
    };
  }, []);
function handleBackButtonOnnclick() {
    storeData();
    navigation.navigate('Home', {
      screen: 'Home',
      params: {
        assessment_age: assessment_age,
      },
    });
    return true;
  }

const storeData = async () => {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.setItem(
        'assessment_age',
        assessment_age.toString(),
      ).then(
        console.log('assessment age stored -->', assessment_age.toString()),
      );
    } catch (e) {
      console.log('assessment age store error--->', e);
    }
  };
```

Hopefully I have clarified my problem which is with every change in nutrition_assessment_age in Screen A I want to rerender the Screen

Please let me know how would I be able to do it. Kinda stuck since long. Any leads would be great.

As per suggested if I cange my useEffect to

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      console.log('nutri ass age', nutrition_assessment_age);
      getNutritionAssessmentage();
      
      if (isValidObject(User) && isValidObject(mSChildId)) {
        if (loadApi == true) {
          getHomeTabMainAPI();
          setLoadApi(false);
          setSelectedChild(getChildFromUserChildrenList());
        }
      } else {
        if (!isValidObject(User) || !isValidObject(mSChildId)) {
          getUserData();
        }
      }
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [User, mSChildId, loadApi, nutrition_assessment_age,navigation]);
```

It is showing up blank, no data is being fetched

Comment: are you using react-navigation for routing?

Comment: yes @AntonioErdeljac

Answer (score 1):

I would make use of `react-navigation` lifecycle methods, check them out [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-lifecycle).

I've experienced the same kind of trouble as you when using react-navigation, since react lifecycles do not fire on navigation changes, thus I would resort to applying this:

#### Example:

Try applying this to Screen A:

```
import { useFocusEffect } from '@react-navigation/native';

function ScreenA() {
  useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      // Screen A is focused, initialize the state, or do whatever checking you need.

      return () => {
        // Screen A is unfocused, clear the state, clear async storage, or whatever you need
      };
    }, [])
  );

  return <div>Screen A!</div>;
}
```

You can also apply this to react's hooks like this:

```
function ScreenA({ navigation }) {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      // Screen was focused
      // Do something
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  }, [navigation]);

  return <div>Screen A!</div>;
}
```

Comment: I have edited my answer as per your suggestion but now my data is not being fetched as in getHomeTabMainAPI() is not being called at all,, any suggestion?